# Should I use InfluxDB or Elasticsearch or others for storing mouse tracking data for websites?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, time-series, influxdb

I'm working on a monitoring system to collect user's mouse data (like movement, click, etc.) when browsing a website. This monitoring system may serve multiple sites. Each site has multiple users (identified by `sessionId`). Each user generates mouse data as follows:

```
{
  "sessionId": "12345",
  "url": "/",
  "width": 1249,
  "height": 1074,
  "events": [
    {
      "timestamp": 2291333,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 931,
      "y": 509,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2291381,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1111,
      "y": 504,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2291413,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1188,
      "y": 504,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2291445,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1214,
      "y": 502,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2291671,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1213,
      "y": 502,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2291671,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1214,
      "y": 502,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292285,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1230,
      "y": 481,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292589,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1203,
      "y": 339,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292622,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1060,
      "y": 468,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292653,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 982,
      "y": 541,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292685,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 961,
      "y": 564,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292901,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1079,
      "y": 456,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2292997,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1247,
      "y": 312,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293205,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1247,
      "y": 314,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293221,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1244,
      "y": 332,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293293,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1222,
      "y": 356,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293365,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1071,
      "y": 385,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293381,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1016,
      "y": 404,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293397,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 971,
      "y": 420,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293421,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 937,
      "y": 434,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293437,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 926,
      "y": 437,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293477,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 905,
      "y": 443,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293485,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 904,
      "y": 443,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293549,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 899,
      "y": 446,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293565,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 889,
      "y": 451,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293629,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 836,
      "y": 489,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293637,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 831,
      "y": 493,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293706,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 759,
      "y": 555,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293725,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 732,
      "y": 603,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293757,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 692,
      "y": 691,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293781,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 666,
      "y": 748,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293805,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 649,
      "y": 794,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2293829,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 645,
      "y": 813,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294005,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 714,
      "y": 777,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294101,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 963,
      "y": 562,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294125,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1007,
      "y": 512,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294149,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1036,
      "y": 479,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294189,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1051,
      "y": 468,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294213,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1057,
      "y": 458,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294237,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1070,
      "y": 442,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294277,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1091,
      "y": 404,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294301,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1101,
      "y": 382,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294366,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 1094,
      "y": 375,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294440,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 872,
      "y": 370,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294469,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 662,
      "y": 407,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294485,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 560,
      "y": 421,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294517,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 374,
      "y": 447,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294541,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 297,
      "y": 461,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294566,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 244,
      "y": 473,
      "isTrusted": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 2294589,
      "type": "mousemove",
      "x": 216,
      "y": 480,
      "isTrusted": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to store such data to DB. Of course I also want admins to easily query the mouse data via my system by exposing a Web UI for example. I know Time Series DB like InfluxDB and log solutions like Elasticsearch can both handle similar data. But which one fits my scenario better? Or neither?

Comment: I would suggest the timeseries data to contain sessionId in each event object. That way its easier to index and query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/). It is designed for collecting analaytics events and querying raw data at high speed.